# How can I make a groupbox anchor to 3 sides of a panel, but respect its location?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a panel with a groupbox inside of it.  I'd like the groupbox to grow and shrink as the panel is resized.  However, the panel has 2 controls that will be placed above the groupbox.  I want to groupbox to always stay beneath those controls.

Since I want it to resize automatically, I've turned on AutoSize.  If I use dock, it of course ignores the location I've set.  I can't seem to make anchors actually do anything.

How can I make the groupbox respect the location I set, but expand to fill the panel downwards and to the left and right?

Comment: Put the groupbox on one panel and the 2 other controls on another. Set the alignment of the top panel with the controls to 'top' and the lower panel with the groupbox, and the groupbox itself to 'client'.  Would that not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see what's the problem, if I understand the question, the WinForms designer is perfectly capable of setting this up. Isn't this working?

```
this.groupBox.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top |
                       AnchorStyles.Bottom |
                       AnchorStyles.Left |
                       AnchorStyles.Right;
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd agree with you, except that my form is doing this when I anchor to all 4 locations and set its location: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/46698764/form1.PNG

Comment: I was developing an addin for Autodesk Inventor.  It turned out to be a sizing bug in their application.  The form would shrink twice as fast as it would grow, thus breaking the anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Should be easy.

- Set AutoSize to false
- position the groupbox inside a panel as you wish
- Set groupbox.Dock to None
- Set groupbox.Anchor to Top, Bottom, Left, Right
- groupbox will now follow the panel. You can set panel.Dock to Fill if it is the only control on the form, or according to your requirements